# Joomla nested ul menu

Tags: menu, joomla1.5

everyone! What I'm trying to do is to get Joomla! to desplay the menu items in a nested ul menu, like this:

- Item

  - Subitem
- Item2

  - Subitem2

    - Sub Subitem

currently I'm using a custom HTML for this, I've written a custom jquery script for this accordion and I'd like to use it with the Joomla's menu system. I've also downloaded Extended Menu module. Please let me know of any ideas.
P.S forgot to say that I don't want to create a dropdown menu that works on hover. My menu should slide down on .click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck. The standard Joomla mod_mainmenu module builds menus exactly like that. You can basically take the entire module, add some IDs and classes to suit your accordion code and add in the JS to have a fully functioning menu with minimal effort. Just to be sure, I moved some menu items around on one of my demo sites. Take a look at the Resources menu here - http://www.internextion.com/

That is a basic Joomla menu module with the items nested as you illustrated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't need main items to have links. Anchors should always be on the last item(subitem). I could do it with JS I guess or is there a way in Joomla to make some menu titles unlinkable. But then again I think that I'll stick with the custom html 'cause it's just lighter and the website runs faster anyways.
But I still would like to know how do you make those titles unlinkable for the accoridon? I know how to do it with JS, but I'm wondering about joomla and whether I should use a core hack or no...

Comment: You can easily make a menu item unclickable my making it a menu type "separator". Turning the mod_mainmenu in to a full blown module that works with the built in Joomla menus makes it very easy to administer, update proof (at least on 1.5.x), and you could then distribute the module in the JED.

I change a couple of the menu items on my demo, is that what you are looking for?